# What does wrapping a variable in {} mean in a reducer function REACT NATIVE?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React native and I came across code for a reducer function but I am confused on why "token" is wrapped in brackets. Does it make token into a dynamic thing or something?

Can someone please explain why it is so? Thank you so much!

```
/** The reducer is in charge of updating the app state based on the dispatched action. **/
//Action Types
export const CREDENTIALED = 'auth/CREDENTIALED';
export const RESET_DATA = 'auth/RESET_DATA';

export const initialState = {
  isLoading: true,
  token: null,
};

//REDUCER
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREDENTIALED: {
      let {token} = action;

      return {...state, isLoading: true, token};
    }

    case RESET_DATA: {
      return {...state, ...initialState};
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a react native expert by any stretch of the imagination, but it looks like token is just being destructured from action. Roughly the same as:

```js
const dict = {
  "alpha": 'a',
  "beta": 'b',
}

const {alpha} = dict

console.log(alpha) // you should expect "a" to be printed out
```

Comment: Also: MDN on destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment (Also, wow, it's more powerful than I thought!)

Comment: Ah! I see! So it's basically grabbing "token" from the dispatch action :). Thank you! It is basically equivalent of saying  "let token = action.token" I believe